# How Can I use super without Cannot refer to an instance field sideC while explicitly invoking a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, super

```
public abstract class Triangle {

 protected double sideA, sideB, sideC;
 
 public Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC) {
     
     this.sideA = sideA;
     this.sideB = sideB;
     this.sideC = sideC;
 }
 
}
```

I would wonder how can I use the super() without the error Cannot refer to an instance field sideC while explicitly invoking a constructor. Below are the code I got error.

```
public RightTriangle(double sideA, double sideB) {

        super(sideA, sideB, sideC);
        this.sideA = sideA;
        this.sideB = sideB;
        this.sideC = getHypotenuse.sideC;

    }
     
    public EquilateralTriangle(double sideLength) {
        
        super(sideA, sideB, sideC);
        super.sideA = sideLength;
        super.sideB = sideLength;
        super.sideC = sideLength;
    }
```

And I also get the error on the code below.
- sideA cannot be resolved or is
not a field
- sideB cannot be resolved or is
not a field
- sideC cannot be resolved or is
not a field

```
EquilateralTriangle et = new EquilateralTriangle(1);
```

Constructor:

```
public EquilateralTriangle(double sideLength) {
        
        super(sideA, sideB, sideC);
        super.sideA = sideLength;
        super.sideB = sideLength;
        super.sideC = sideLength;
    }
```

Why this constructor cannot be called in new EquilateralTriangle(1) ?
Please help me to figure it out these.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first, you are not using the super constructor correctly. There is lot of info online, start with [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html). To summarize it, invoking the super constructor with some parameters in the child class contructor will pass the parameters to it, and will do the operations you declared in it(validating and setting the fields in your case). You don't need to set the fields by hand after invoking it. You can think of it as invoking a special type of method.

Right triangle will look like this:

```
public class RightTriangle extends Triangle {

    public RightTriangle(double sideA, double sideB) {
        super(sideA, sideB, calculateHypotenuse(sideA, sideB));
    }

    private static double calculateHypotenuse(double sideA, double sideB) {
        //implement it, using the formula
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        //implement it using formula
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see call to super constructor is first stamement in this contructor, and passing to it parameters from this constructor(sideA and sideB). Hypotenuse(sideC) is calculated using `static` method, it is not possible to use `this` when invoking super constructor.

Equilateral triangle will look like that:

```
public class EquilateralTriangle extends Triangle {

    public EquilateralTriangle(double sideLength) {
        super(sideLength, sideLength, sideLength);
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        //calculate it using formula
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note how sideLength is passed as every parameter in the super constructor(sideA, sideB, sideC). The super constructor will set and validate them. This should fix all compilation problems you have.

Comment: Thank you very much . You are very kind

Comment: @HollyWong You are welcome. If this answer actually did solve your problem, you can accept it.